# Does a REVERT operation in the EVM clear the stack?

Tags: python

I was experimenting with the playground on [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/playground) and I came across something strange. The op codes of my test contract are: PUSH1
PUSH32
PUSH1
MSTORE
PUSH1
PUSH1
REVERT

Whats strange to me is that after the REVERT operation is executed, the UI seems to indicate that whatever remained on the stack when revert is executed would remain on the stack. I was of the impression that revert would clear the stack before the next transaction. Does this data persist in someway, or is it a quirk of the playground UX?